# How should I implement a one-to-one relationship in (My)SQL?

Tags: sql

I'm relatively new to SQL and I'm not sure how to do a one to one relationship.  Having read about the first 3 forms of normalization, I'm currently under the impression that the best way to do this would be to have an intermediary table, ala-3rd from many to many relationships, except each column being declared unique.

Comment: A one-to-one relationship means either a) there should only be one table or b) the relationship needs to be reclassified so it is a one-to-many or many-to-many.

Comment: @OMG Ponies I don't fully agree with that. You can have another table with a one-to-one relationship. It doesn't always make any sense to do that but I'm sure someone could think of a reason for it

Comment: @do3boy: Databases also let you create tables that don't pass 1NF.  Just because you can, doesn't mean you should.

Comment: I think having every field in a separate table would be *technically* more normalized than having it all in one table. That's silly though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ImageDetails
------------
id (PK)
name
description


ImageData
------------
id (PK & FK)
blobfield
```

Something like this might be a good reason/way to do a one-to-one relationship but normally you would just have all your data in one table where each row is what defines the relationship.

One reason for separating them might be to limit access to a specific table for a user while allowing access to other data for that key field.

Another possible reason for having a separate table for a one-to-one relationship is when you do not wish to have `null` in your column. For instance, if 90% of the data will be null, you may be better off with a completely separate (and smaller) table and joining that field on the PK instead. This is actually considered to be an "optional one-to-one relationship" because you do not truly have one record for every possible relationship.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a third table for one-to-one relationship, but if the relationship is many-to-many then you do need a third intermediary table between them.

Answer (score 0):

Optional one-to-one relationships do come up in the real world. The easiest way to implement them, IMHO, is with a unique foreign-key.

```
mysql> describe table_one;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| table_two_id | int(11)      | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
0 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe table_two;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
0 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```